# can I use android farsi plugin in my app

Tags: android

I want to use farsi language in my app .I want device that don't support farsi can disply it goodly.I search on web lot and I find classes for this but I want simple way for it.my question is that can I use [farsi plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=klye.plugin.fa&hl=en) for it?if no then is there plugin for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, sure you may use it but prior to using this  you need to install a MultiLing Keyboard along with this plugin. This plugin works wonderfully and you can also enjoy the auto-correct and word suggestion for Persian language.

Comment: hello I want to use it with my custom keyboard.I design a custom keyboard for my app.my question is that can I use farsi plugin for my keyboard in app?